# Receive chat from non-friend from Facebook Chat API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-chat

I've logged in and used the Facebook CHAT api all right. The problem is that I want to have a system where anyone can send me a message, without actually being on the friend list.

When the sender is in the friend list, I see the message. Is there a possibility that I can configure my account to receive messages from anyone, independing on if they are in the friend list or not?

Best Regards.

Comment: That would go against Facebook's privacy policy.  You won't get that functionality from their Chat API...

Comment: Right, but can I specifically configure MY account to accept chat from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The Chat API and the Message API are not the same.

You may want to think of Chat as a subset of messages.

When a message is received and the user is a friend you receive a chat notification, if not, no response.